# Deplying Flask on Heroku and hiding Database Key

Tags: python, heroku, flask

https://medium.com/the-andela-way/deploying-a-python-flask-app-to-heroku-41250bda27d0

I am following this article to deploy my flask app on Heroku.
However, I hid my database connection keys and did not commit them on my GitHub repo.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from pymongo import MongoClient, TEXT
from langdetect import detect
import json
import utils
import config

connection_str = config.connection_str
db_name = config.db_name

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
client = MongoClient(connection_str)
db = client.get_database(db_name)
```

I need the `connection_str` and `db_name` which is from `utils` and it's not committed.

The article does not explain how to hide these keys or retrieve it from somewhere else when I deploy a Flask app. Any help?

Comment: Have I answered your question? Please mark my answer correct if I have.

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance. Your answer really helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku has a method of providing secrets with [environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). You may access these via `os.environ`.

To set:

```sh
heroku config:set db_name=foo-name
heroku config:set connection_str=your-connection-string-here
```

To access:

```py
import os

print(os.environ["db_name"])
print(os.environ["connection_str"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Set environment variables (change YOURAPPNAME to your app name):
https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/YOURAPPNAME/settings#ember553

Get environment variables:

```py
os.getenv("db_name")
os.getenv("connection_str")
```